# Is it personification to say that something inanimate requires something?

Tags: personification

I personally do not think this is personification but can find no guidance one way or the other that is specific enough. If someone has advice or better yet a link to guidance proving one way or the other, I'd appreciate it.

- The Construction General Permit requires implementation of erosion control measures
- Bird law requires nesting bird surveys prior to construction.

Please tell me whether this is personification and why or why not.

Comment: Interesting question. It is at best a weak metaphor/personification. For X to require or need something, one might suppose that X is sentient, to be aware of that need. And historically, before some technological point, 'need' may have only ever been used with people. But to use it with objects is not some great leap.

Answer (score 1):

"require" is not a verb **requiring** a personal subject. Actually, it can be understood to mean "establish" or "set forth a requirement." The same thing happens with the verbs "order", "instruct", "recommend" and so many others. Being a human creation, laws and regulations can also be said to express the requirements or specifications imposed by lawmakers.

Anyway, I insist that "require" can be used with inanimate subjects, and this does not entail their personification. Another example:

- This game requires a lot of concentration.

Edit: Following TaliesinMerlin's suggestion, here follow some definitions and examples from dictionaries which endorse my position as to the verb "require" not requiring an animate, let alone personal, subject:

- [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/require):
  *Bringing up children often requires you to put their needs first.*
  *The rules require that you bring only one guest to the dinner.*
- [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/require):
  *This isn't the kind of crisis that requires us to drop everything else.*
  *The rules also require employers to provide safety training.*
  *At least 35 manufacturers have flouted a law requiring prompt reporting of such malfunctions.* 
  *The law requires that employees are given the opportunity to improve their performance before they are dismissed.*
- [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/require):
  *The occasion requires formal dress.*
- [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/require):
  *‘the minimum car insurance required by law’*
- [Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/require):
  *Campbell’s broken leg will probably require surgery.*
  *Most houseplants require regular watering.*
  *Regulations require that students attend at least 90% of the lectures.*
  *Accounting rules require that corporate financial statements disclose the updated value of assets.*
- [American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=require):
  *The law requires full disclosure of charitable donations.*
  *Skiing requires practice.*

Comment: I didn’t downvote your answer, but *insisting* on an answer doesn’t help the community judge whether it is correct.

Comment: @Lawrence It is clear to me that "require" does not require (notice the use) an animate subject and tried to make it as clear as possible in my answer. People may like it or not. I'm already used to the fact that some members will downvote no matter how much effort one devotes to one's answers. SE can be irrational. I no longer care. My use of the verb *insist* does not show obstinacy but is merely a rhetorical device if you read my answer carefully.

Comment: @Gustavson I agree with the content of your answer. That said, a link to a dictionary or another source would further support what you're saying. For instance, in a quick skim of the OED entry for "require," many definitions require a personal subject, but some do not. Merriam-Webster doesn't specify subjects explicitly, but its definition 2a allows for nonpersonal subjects ("the occasion requires ...").

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin Thank you for your suggestion. I followed your advice.